# Where is the documentation for xml attributes like layout_column, layout_height?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to learn Android App Dev and after I ran through this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html
And I want to know what are the other possible values that could be assigned to XML attributes like layout_width or layout_height?
And what does layout_column actually do?
But I can't seem to find the documentation for these attributes

Where on developer.android.com can I find what I exactly need?

Answer (score 1):

All of the XML Attributes are listed within each 'view' on the developer website, for instance, all the XML attributes for a LinearLayout are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html).